# Flutter error: No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-windows

I am new to Flutter. When I want to run my Flutter application on Windows, I get this error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.



Building Windows application...
Exception: Unable to generate build files
```

Here is the output of `flutter doctor -v`:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1586], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.10.4 at E:\Flutter\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision c860cba910 (4 days ago), 2022-03-25 00:23:12 -0500
    • Engine revision 57d3bac3dd
    • Dart version 2.16.2
    • DevTools version 2.9.2

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0-rc4)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\moham\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0-rc4
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.1.2)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.1.32319.34
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0

[√] Android Studio (version 4.2)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1586]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 99.0.4844.84
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 98.0.1108.62

[√] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Everything is OK. Where is the problem is?

I read all the previous answers, but nothing worked for me.

Comment: This seems like a contradiction: *"Everything is OK. I don't know where the problem is!"*. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, but I don't know what the solution is exactly.

I think the solution was to uninstall the whole "Desktop Development With C++" from Visual Studio and reinstall it.

Then in the directory of my Flutter project:

`flutter clean`
and
`flutter create .`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe go to [Android Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio), menu *File* → *Settings* → *Appearance & Behavior* → *System Settings* → *SDK Tools*.

Check if the `CMake` field is checked.

Another one:

Check if the developer option is checked in (in Windows)* *Settings* → *Update & Security* → *For developers* → *Developer mode* (if it's off, make it on).

Comment: yes, CMake and developer mode is already checked in

Comment: are you on emulator ?

Comment: No i am trying to run a windows application why do i need emulator

Comment: no i mean you are on mac os and mace win emulator

Comment: no, I am currently working on windows 10