# Cannot build a Flutter Desktop app on Windows 11

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, flutter-desktop

I am getting this error in Android Studio when I chose Windows (Desktop) from the dropdown list and click on Play. This is a Desktop Flutter created project:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
Building Windows application...
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.



Exception: Unable to generate build files
```

Things I have done:

- Installed Visual Studio Code with the Development and Windows SDKs installed
- Installed CMake through the SDK manager on Android Studio

Flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22622.598], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.3.5)
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2021.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.69.1)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
    ! Device emulator-5554 is offline.
    ! Device emulator-5562 is offline.
[√] HTTP Host Availability
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter error: No CMAKE\_CXX\_COMPILER could be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71652256/flutter-error-no-cmake-cxx-compiler-could-be-found)

Comment: @Kurt No, I have tried both answers there. I've googled this before but my error stays the same despite the common answers.